# How to get Cookie from page created in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, web, cookies

*Note*

> Time: 2022.01.06 12:03

> Some time later I explained to my superiors
> that the use of Delphi to create a site is not the best idea,
> instead persuaded to use PHP.

> Thank you to everyone who participated!

I'm new in Delphi and also sorry for my bad English.
I'm using Embarcadero Rad Studio Delphi 10.3.
I need to create Site with delphi, so I create new project
"Delphi\web\webserver application\windows\stand-alone GUI application\vcl application"

in WebModuleUnit (visual view), window "structure" I chose branch of my page and in 
windows "Object Inspector" go to page "events" --> I create event in "OnAction" field
Then I switch to code view and in "WMTestPageAction" procedure wrote this code

```
procedure TWebModule1.WMTestPageAction(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
  var
   tstStr:tstrings;
  const 
   cookieUserName='UserNameXYZ';
begin

  Response.Content :=
    '<!DOCTYPE html>'+
    '<html>'+
    '<head>'+
      '<title>Test page</title>'+
    '</head>'+
    '<body>';


tstStr:=TStringList.Create;

//Request.Create;
Request.ExtractCookieFields(tstsTr);
Response.Content :=Response.Content+'<div>test output<br>'+
'get cookie name User = '+cookieUserName+' ; Request.Cookie  = '+Request.Cookie +'<br>'+
'get cookie name User = '+cookieUserName+' ; inttostr(Request.Cookie.Length)  = '+inttostr(Request.Cookie.Length) +'<br>'+
'get cookie name User = '+cookieUserName+' ; Request.ContentFields.Text  = '+Request.ContentFields.Text +'<br>'+
'get cookie name User = '+cookieUserName+' ; Request.ContentFields.Values[''UserNameXYZ'']  = '+Request.ContentFields.Values['UserNameXYZ'] +'<br>'+
'get cookie name Token= '+cookieUserToken+' ; Request.ContentFields.Values[cookieUserToken] = '+Request.ContentFields.Values[cookieUserToken]+'<br>'+
' Request.Content = '+ Request.Content +'<br>'+
' tstsTr.Text = '+ tstsTr.Text +'<br>'+

'<br>Response<br>'+
' Response.HTTPRequest.Cookie '+ Response.HTTPRequest.Cookie +'<br>'+
' Response.Cookies.Count = '+ IntToStr(Response.Cookies.Count) +'<br>'+
' Response.GetCustomHeader(''name2'') = '+ Response.GetCustomHeader('name2') +'<br>'+

' Response.GetCustomHeader(''name2'') = '+ '' +'<br>'+

'</div>';

Response.Content :=Response.Content+'</body></html>';
end;
```

in "response" I can form my page and I use this to get test info,
I can set Cookie with `Response.SetCookieField(scValues,scDomen,scPath,scExpiries,scSecure);`
but I can't get cookie in delphi on loading page, all what I try I wrote in code.

in browser console on command `document.cookie`
I recive`"name2=value2; UserNameXYZ=jack; token=sd78sd78s7d8s"`

I want to check user session on each load of all the pages in my site.
Respone and Request in code belongs to module "Web.HTTPApp".

Please advice.

*Edits*

```
// 12:30 I comment line with:
Request.Create; //did'nt help
```

- tstsTr variable created only for reason to get cookie, I think that I use something wrong or I miss something.

Comment: Why are you calling `Request.Create`? That doesn't belong, get rid of it. Also, you are leaking `tstStr`.

Comment: Request.Create probably simply destroys the Request contents(along with the cookies in it). You should not create the Request - it is already created and being passed to your procedure. I think just removing the line Request.Create will make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finaly find info [from embarcadero in 1999](https://community.embarcadero.com/article/technical-articles/147-enterprise/12317-working-with-cookies)

```
procedure TWebModule1.WebModule1WebActionItem3Action(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Response.Content := '';
  for i := 0 to (Request.CookieFields.Count - 1) do
  begin
    Response.Content := Response.Content + '

' +
    Request.CookieFields[i] + '
';
  end;
  Response.Content := Response.Content + '';
end;
```

For Extract I Use

```
function getCookieFieldByName(Sender:TStrings;vCookieName:string):string;
var i:Integer;
begin
  result:='';
  for i := 0 to (Sender.Count - 1) do
  begin
   if Pos( vCookieName+'=',Sender[i] ) >0 then
   begin
    result:= Sender[i];
    result:= Copy(result, Pos('=',result)+1 );
    Break;
   end;
  end;
end;
```

and call looks like this

```
result := getCookieFieldByName(Request.CookieFields,cookieUserName);
```